# Two Compact Dryers on a 30 Amp Circuit

Tags: dryer

I have seen the question about having two dryers on the same circuit answered several times. The answer is usually that you should put them on separate circuits. I understand that for traditional dryers.

But what about this scenario? Circuit is 208 volts / 30 amps. The two dryers would be condenser/ventless dryers rated at 2800W each. Seems like the maximum amp draw would be about 13.5 X 2 = 27 amps. In this situation could I simply use splitter like this: [image]

Comment: can you post a nameplate photo for your dryer? Dryers are *not* constant power loads...they're actually close to, but not quite, *constant resistance* loads due to the big heating element.

Answer (score 1):

I refer you to NEC Article and Table 210.21(B)(2) which states and shows that a 30A branch circuit supplying two or more cord and plug connected loads shall not exceed 24A. Your assumption of 27A would in violation of the NEC.

Sorry for the disappointment.

Comment: Okay, that is important to know. ... To look a little closer, the dryer's documentation says that it is rated: 240V, 2800W, 12A. The same documentation also states that it works with 208V, which is what I have, so I am assuming that the unit would still trying to use 2800W and therefore would be drawing closer to 13.5A on my circuit. However when I asked about the affect of a 208V circuit GE's forum they answered that it would not get as hot and take longer to dry, so maybe it's still using just 12A and closer to 2500W in this case?

Comment: @TWW - This is where things can get weird. If you divide 2800W by 240V the result would be 12A, but if you divide 2800W by 208V it would be 13.5A. Amperage is indirectly proportional to the voltage which means each amperage is correct depending on operational voltage. So the question is what is the actual operating voltage of your service. It could be either one but you have said it is 208V. You need to confirm your actual operating voltage.

Comment: @TWW - Also if you notice you are claiming that your dryers use 2800W. Note that Wattage is VA (volt/amps) * efficiency multiplier. Try and find the actual nameplate of the dryers and see if it has information such as the actual amperage use or a VA rating or an Efficiency rating. Otherwise the only other way I know of doing it is with an ammeter under actual conditions.

Comment: I finally got an answer from GE: The dryer is rated for 240V/12A and 208V/10A.